# angularjs provide decorator log dont see debug method

Tags: angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.config(function($provide) {
             $provide.decorator( '$log', function( $delegate ){
                // Save the original $log.debug()
                var debugFn = $delegate.debug;
                console.log(debugFn);
                $delegate.debug = function( )
                {

                };

                return $delegate;
            });

        });
```

I'm wondering why console.log(debugFn);

is undefined (if I use for instance log or an other method it works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you using a version of Angular that has the debug function on the `$log` service. The debug function was introduced with version 1.1.2. See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#112-tofu-animation-2013-01-22